# VS 2015 Installer project - Dependencies with older version Number than installed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have an app that uses a VS 2015 installer project.

Our BONEHEAD vendor, ComponentOne, released a new version of several assemblies upon which my product depends.

Here's the rub:
Old DLL version: 4.1.20102...
New DLL Version: **4.0.20162**...

The newer DLL at least have newer file dates than the older one.

Of course, the newer DLL fix real user problems brought about by the bugs in the C1 components since corrected.

While I can get to the correct DLL by having the end user fully uninstall the older version of my product and installing the newer version, this is unworkable because:

1. We have an auto-update function that phones home and checks for the latest patch and installs it to update prevoius version; and
2. Our customers are female, 60+ and cyberphobic.

The project already has the *RemovePreviousVersions* property set to true, and I was hoping that this did a complete uninstall silently.  It does not; the six assemblies with the version error are not replaced. The *DetectNewerInstalledVersion* property is also set to true; I tried to install with False, and it has no effect.

I also tried to explicitly include all detected dependencies of the C1 assemblies and it has no effect.

Is there a way to force the install project to overwrite the assemblies as long as the file date is newer regardless of the wrongly-encoded version?

**Edited to add the following:**

1. I tried making a custom action to delete the offending assemblies before installing anything - it runs after the files are installed. :(
2. I tried InstallShield LE, only to find out that it could not discover the dependencies more than one level deep, and provided no convenient way to explicitly specify the dependencies.  I also could find nothing that would let me say to overwrite the assemblies based on date or unconditionally.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

I found an effective workaround.

I already had RemovePreviousVersions set to true, so I changed the application's default folder by adding **[ProductVersion]** onto the end of the path.

What this accomplished was:

1. It deleted the old assemblies; and
2. It created the new assemblies in the new folder.

This solved the problem nicely.  No setting REINSTALLMODE to *amus*; no brute force solutions.